# curl and mbstring php 7.1 installation on ubuntu 17.04

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl, php-7.1

I'm using php7.1 on Ubuntu 17.04, I have tried to install cURL using this command:

```
sudo apt-get install php-curl
```

but I get this:

> Package 'php-curl' has no installation candidate

I tried also to specify the cURL version using:

```
sudo apt-get install php7.1-curl
```

but i got

> E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.1-curl

So, please, how do I install curl for PHP 7.1?

Answer (score 10):

You need to add PHP ppa first, update, and install

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ondrej/php
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install php7.1-curl
```

Answer (score 1):

While it seems strange that you are not able to find `php-curl`, you should search for php curl package version available on your system:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt search ^php
```

Between the results, it should display something like this (the output was taken from Ubuntu 17.10, yours will be different):

```
php7.1-curl/artful-updates,artful-security 7.1.15-0ubuntu0.17.10.1 amd64
      CURL module for PHP
```

then, you just install it as usual:

```
sudo apt install php7.1-curl
```

happy coding!